# Nim言語のソースコードでpythonのnumpyを使えるようにする方法について

Tags: python, python3, numpy, nimble

Nim言語のソースコードでpythonのライブラリのnumpyを使いたかったので以下のような簡単なコードを書きました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、以下のようにエラーが出てしまいました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こういう時はどう対処すれば良いのでしょうか。
私はpythonはanaconda3経由で使っています。また、既にNimはインストール済みです。そして、コマンドプロンプト上ではpipや、conda、nim, nimbleを使えるようにしてあります。nimble install nimpyでnimpyも使えるようにしています。またpythonにおいてnumpyを使えるようにしてあります。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので参考にしてみては？ [Nimpyでnimからpythonを呼ぶ](https://qiita.com/kixixixixi/items/b9b34030959fe718ab93), [nimpyでnimからpythonを使って主成分分析をする](https://qiita.com/kixixixixi/items/be4d09a8959f93e6ed61), [zaferarican/nimpy_numpy_examples](https://github.com/zaferarican/nimpy_numpy_examples), [Nimpy and Arraymancer](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6321)